# Prepopulate a choice field by a model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Im new to Django development and have a question regarding choice fields.

I want to populate a choice field by a model:

```py
# function.py
[1] ingredients = Ingredients.objects.all()
[2] extras = Extras.objects.filter(pizza_id=pizza_id)

[3] form = SelectIngredientsForm(extras,ingredients)
```

```py
# forms.py
# Note its Form not ModelForm
class SelectIngredientsForm(forms.Form):
[4]    ingredients = forms.ChoiceField(choices=X)
[5]    extras = forms.ChoiceField(choices=X)
```

**My Question is**: How can I populate the choices in the Form ([4] and [5]) with the objects I have got previously [3] from object [1] and object [2]?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ModelChoiceField instead.

```
from functions import ingredients, extras 

class SelectIngredientsForm(forms.Form):

    ingredients = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ingredients)
    extras =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=extras)
```

Comment: As I have them in 2 different code locations, can you tell me how I can acchieve exactly this, but in that way like I do in [3]

Comment: Or how can I pass pizza_id to the Form dynamically as I dont know it before. [sorry cant edit my previous comment]